# MVC C# Search Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to filter records from my database. Checkbox value post controller when checkbox checked.

When I choose "a", it'll show which  record contains "a", 
But when I choose "a,b", It's showing "a - b - a,b " but I just want it to show "a,b".

My controller:

```
   public ActionResult GetProducts(List<string> filter)
   {
        List<Product> proc = new List<Product>();

        foreach (var item in filter)
        { 
           var model = db.Product.Where(x => x.tMal.Contains(item)).ToList();
            proc.AddRange(model);
        }
        return View(proc);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Either you search for an exact match or you search partially. Which one you want?

Comment: I only want records that contain both "a" and "b" @EzLo

Comment: Can you clarify the requirement a bit? Is the goal to have the filters be applied with "and" logical operators as opposed to "or"? Currently, your code effectively operates as "or" - that is, you will return all results that contain at least one of the filter strings.

Comment: I want both of them to match (a and b together) not just a or just b @DavidJetter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to chain several `Where()` with a different `Contains()` from your filters before retrieving your values from the database:

```
public ActionResult GetProducts(List<string> filter)
{
    List<Product> proc = new List<Product>();

    IQueryable<Product> query = db.Product;

    foreach (var item in filter)
        query = query.Where(x => x.tMal.Contains(item));

    proc.AddRange(query.ToList());

    return View(proc);
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add the extra `Where` clause.

Comment: Are you sure @CelalBahadırKAYA? Doesn't return duplicates when I test. If you have duplicate records, it may.

Comment: Yes I'm sure @ibrahimozgon same id,same name

Comment: I wrote my example above, it seems fine.

Answer (score 2):

According to @Ezlo answer, I just tested it with some data, I couldn't write this in answer. When I run

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = GetProducts(new List<string> { "a", "b" });
            foreach (var val in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Result:" + val);
            }

        }

        public static IEnumerable<string> GetProducts(List<string> filter)
        {
            List<Product> proc = new List<Product>();

            IQueryable<Product> query = new List<Product>
            {
                new Product
                {
                    tMal = "a,b",
                },
                new Product
                {
                    tMal = "a",
                },
                new Product
                {
                    tMal = "b",
                }
            }.AsQueryable();

            foreach (var item in filter)
            {
                query = query.Where(x => x.tMal.Contains(item));
            }

            proc.AddRange(query.ToList());
            return proc.Select(s => s.tMal);
        }
    }

    internal class Product
    {
        public string tMal;
    }
```

This is the result I got:

```
Result:a,b
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was adding product to list in foreach loop :) ,I fixed

Comment: Glad it helped!